# new Chrome Web Inspector open causes flashing for blurred and animated element

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web-app I've built which uses CSS3 to blur an element with a background image while simultaneously animating it in a circular path.

About 5-10 days ago (I can't remember exactly when) Google Chrome updated and now this combination (blur plus animation) causes a flashing effect ONLY when the Chrome web inspector is open.

To see what I'm talking about, view the following simplified demonstration jsfiddle in a current build of Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredh159/qqchW/1/

Then, open the web inspector and reload, you'll see the flashing. Close the inspector and the flashing stops.

Is this a problem with my code? Or a bug in Chrome? Is there a workaround? Does anyone have any insight? Safari's web inspector does not cause the same flashing.

Here's the CSS and HTML:

```
<style>
    @-webkit-keyframes bgOrbit {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(50px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(50px) rotate(-360deg); }
    }

    div.wrap {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
   }

    .img {
        background-image: url(http://www.prophoto.com/jsfiddle/thumb.jpg);
    position: absolute;
        width: 120%;
        height: 120%;
        top: 80px;
        left: 80px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
        -webkit-animation: 3s bgOrbit linear infinite;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. It smells like a Chrome bug as it disappears as soon as the blur filter is off. Perhaps report it to them.

Comment: http://crbug.com/new is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

As of Chrome 55, this is no longer an issue. If anyone coming here is experiencing something similar, please open a new question.

Comment: Would help to provide background on why. You can confirm it was fixed, or you didn't notice it?

Comment: Well, this is kind of an old answer, but based on what I said, I'm guessing that it's officially fixed. I don't think I would have said that if I just didn't notice it. lol